# Excel Javascript API - join range or complex range selection

Tags: excel, office-js

In Excel macro you can do something simple like:

`Range("C8:G8,C12:H12,C19:I19").Value = 1`

this gives me an opportunity to create a complex range selection and reduce the number of api calls and sync queue.

But when I do

```
const range = activeWorkSheet.getRange("C8:G8,C12:H12,C19:I19");       
range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
```

I get

> InvalidArgument: The argument is invalid or missing or has an
>   incorrect format.

There is also no getJoinRange or getUnionRange I could use.

Is there a workaround? I am having some performance issue as I do thing like format a row based on odd/even.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beta feature forthcoming, which will allow multi-area ranges.  Its syntax is still TBD, it might be exactly what you wrote (with range being allowed to be a multi-area range), or perhaps we'll keep Range a single contiguous object and have parallel methods like `worksheet.getMultiAreaRange("C8:G8, C12:H12, C19:I19`) to do what you would like.

Also, what version of Office do you have and are you on Insider Fast, by any chance?

Re. performance, can you post your exact use-case as a minimal snippet?  There may be some optimizations you can do, even barring multi-area ranges.

**Update**

If all you're doing is a 3x3 or a 5x5 (i.e., not something super-huge), you don't need multi-area support.  You can just do:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const rowCount = 5;
    const columnCount = 5;
    const range = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, rowCount, columnCount);
    for (let row = 0; row < rowCount; row = row + 2) {
        range.getRow(row).format.fill.color = "purple";
    }

    await context.sync()
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Sorry for the delay. I can't be on Insider Fast as I am building something for a client and the user won't be on Insider Fast. One of the use case is quite simple, format an odd even rows, but on 3 by 3 or 5 by 5 groups.

Comment: If you're doing a 3x3 or a 5x5, you don't need multi-area.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I meant, having a row with formatting A and a row with formatting B in a permutation. example: [link](https://www.nukon.com.au/hs-fs/hubfs/Smart%20Planner/Nukon-Supply-chain-planning-with-smart-planner.gif?t=1530859887098&width=480&name=Nukon-Supply-chain-planning-with-smart-planner.gif)

Comment: Sure, but you can still do that via manipulating one row after another, without multi-area.

Comment: Yes. Problem is performance, which is what I'm trying to optimise. Its currently taking 60s to load my sheet with all formats. It works, but the macro version I have that does the same thing but in a smarter way takes 2 secs on the same data size.

Comment: @Rafael, just to be clear that we're not talking about two separate issues:  is the 60 seconds for *opening* the file once it's been colored using the APIs, or is it 60 seconds to *do the coloring*?  Both would be bad, obviously.  If it's the latter, I might have a workaround for you soon.  If it's the former, than something is seriously amiss in how we write to the file, but I don't *think* it's the case -- if it is, would you mind opening a bug on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues?

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the support. This link I'm sharing is to a sheet that gets produced, so you can see the requirements I have. I've added a pseudo code steps to explain the type of api I am using and the algorithm logic. This will look at first over complicated, but it is a result of a few iterations trying to optimise the loading time. It has indeed improved, but had I had complex selection, I would have removed most of the complexity. Note that I also use macro functions on some of the calcs.[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uudpJj7dtRRUjF_ng9qayJbV9kgMGh6Q/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: OK, I see.  You are definitely creating a bunch of Range objects in those loops, so I can see how that would be slowing things down.  The good news is that on newer Excel builds, and using JavaScript that will be on the Office.js CDN in a week-and-a-half or so, you'll be able to do an optimization that should definitely speed things up, a lot.

Comment: If you are on a "current channel" (or better yet, Insiders channel) of Office and if you reference https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js@1.1.9-adhoc.8/dist/office.js instead of your current CDN location (just for testing, until it's on the CDN), you can try it out.  With these two prerequisites in place, try calling "untrack()" after every operation that creates a cell.  Yes, it's a bit tedious, but the perf gain should be significant.

Comment: I.e., `(activeWorksheet.getCell(i, insertData.planningDateColumnStartIndex - 1).getBoundingRect(activeWorkSheet.getCell(i, insertData.columnCount - 1).untrack()) as Excel.Range).untrack()`.  Note there were two "untracks()" there, both inside and outside.  They tell the host that you don't intend to use these ranges again after the current "context.sync()", which I think in your code is true (and is certainly true of any intermediate ranges you create, when calling "getBoundingRange" for example)

Comment: Give it a try and let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: Great. Thanks for that.